# iOS Parse.com updating objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am building a photo sharing app using parse as my backend. Now I want to update the numberOfLikes attribute of each photo object after the user clicks the like button, using:

```
[photoObject incrementKey:@"numberOfLikes"];
[photoObject saveInBackground];
```

My question is, lets say several users liked the same photo at the same time, will these like requests be in a processing queue? (Will Parse handle them one by one?)Assuming this photo has 0 likes, then 5 users like it at the same time, given that the network conditions are the same, will the final result after saving be 1 or 5?

Sorry if this question looks silly or my description is confusing. I am pretty new to Parse. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain functions in Parse are atomic, incrementKey happens to be one of them.

https://parse.com/questions/concurrency-management-in-parse

> The incrementKey method is atomic when saving. So the process goes like this:
>
> Player A calls the incrementKey method on the Prize, and attempts to save (with a callback function.)
>   Player B calls the incrementKey method on the Prize, and attempts to save (with a callback function.)
>   Either Player A or Player B's callback runs, the numberOfWins is 6.
>   The remaining Players callback runs, the numberOfWins is 7.

You could also implement some sort of locking mechanism using these functions as seen in this question.

https://parse.com/questions/locking

> David's solution is clever and works (incrementKey is atomic). If a GameRequest object is created with a "challengers" : 0 value, then each challenger could call incrementKey:@"challengers". If, after save, the value of challengers is 1, then they are the first committed challenger. I particularly like this solution since it works for N player games as well. Similarly, you can use addUnique: (also atomic) to add a User ID to a list of challengers.

Finally to answer your question, it should be 5 as they are executed one after another and not concurrently.

Comment: Wow thank you for this perfect answer! I wish I can give you more reputation! Thank you!