# Most efficient way of storing data which can be accessed and changed by all users

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm currently in the process of learning both Swift and Parse and for the question I'm asking I'm going to use a simple up vote on a cell.

So I've got a table view controller which is populated by a query to a table on Parse. To do this I create a query on the relevant table and then store the bits of information into arrays e.g. an array for usernames, and text posts and object ID's:

```
var postGrabber: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
var pSenderUsername: [String] = [String]()
var pPostBody: [String] = [String]()
var objectId: [String] = [String]()
```

I can then use the indexPath of a cell to get the relevant information from the arrays above.

Each cell also has a UIButton (for casting a vote as well as other information).

[image: Like so...]

To get the `indexPath` of which cell has been clicked I use:

```
    let btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: btnPos)!
    let rowToAction = indexPath.first!
```

> As a side note, objectAtIndexPath(rowToAction) does not seem to work in Swift 3, does anyone know of an alternative?

From this point I'm a little unsure of the most efficient way of updating my Parse table's score attribute.

After looking at the Parse docs, I could potentially use a counter variable to save a score or an array.

Though, I think if that there could be syncronization issues in using a counter in the case that multiple users are trying to access the data at any one given time. **(Unsure)**

Is it possible that someone could share their way of doing such a task possibly so that the data from Parse can only be accessed by 1 user at any 1 given time to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to increment the `numberOfUpVotes`.

You can use

```
[post incrementKey:@"numberOfUpVotes"];
[post saveInBackground];
```

This will update the votes asynchronously, and the `incrementKey` method is atomic. Let's say we have 5 users clicking on the "up" button at the same time, the value for key "numberOfUpVotes" will be 5 in stead of 1.

Also, you can specify your increment amount by :

```
[post incrementKey:@"numberOfUpVotes" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]
```

But I don't think this is gonna happen in your use case :)

You can read this post from Parse:

https://parse.com/questions/concurrency-management-in-parse

or you can see my question:

[iOS Parse.com updating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244583/ios-parse-com-updating-objects)

> note: my code is in Objective-C, but it's pretty easy to convert that
>   into Swift.

Comment: Ah right thank you. Glad you cleared that up for me :)!

Comment: @F.Bar No problem mate :D

Comment: On a side note, do you know any work around from using the following: 
`let something = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) to get the id of said object. I seem to get an unresolved identifier issue?

Comment: @F.Bar Maybe try array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)? Or simply array[indexPath.row]? I'm not familiar with Swift

Comment: @F.Bar By the way are you using PFQueryTableViewController? Or UITableViewController?

Comment: UITableViewController

Comment: I didn't know there was such thing as a PFQueryTableViewController xD

Comment: @F.Bar You should check PFQueryTableViewController. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736768/how-to-create-a-pfquerytableviewcontroller-with-parse-in-swift

Comment: Just read a little on it... why had I not heard of it?! Cheers for that mate

Comment: @F.Bar Yeah, it's pretty handy. Also check the ParseUI open source: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS